# PayPal IPN Subscriber Amount Paid variable not available

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the PHP version of Paypal IPN, and have the following code to determine if there is an amount paid on the callback from paypal:

[code]

```
if(isset($_POST['mc_amount1'])){
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_amount1'];
}elseif(isset($_POST['mc_gross'])){
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
}elseif(isset($_POST['payment_gross'])){    
    $payment_amount = $_POST['payment_gross'];
}else{
    $payment_amount = "Amount Not Available";
}
```

[/code]

The problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt, pay attention that my buyers are subscribers, they dont pay just an item they subscribe to me. But I had 2 accounts paid from same paypal and one query was the correct amount and the other one was amount not available, while when I checked the paypal ipn response it was exactly the same on both, just the user variable changed, but why it didn't catch the amount the second time?

Any tips will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the transaction type of the IPN message (variable "txn_type"). For example, if "txn_type" is "recurring_payment_profile_created", then "mc_gross" is not present. In this case, you can see the amount in "amount" variable. I think "mc_gross" is used for one-time payment or recurring payment. So you need to check the transaction type first before checking on the amount variable.

For your reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/